# EF 4.1, POCO: Is any way to get Table name in runtime to avoid hardcode?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

I use POCO in Entity Framework. Is any direct or indirect way in the latest EF version to get Table name at the runtime to avoid hardcode values?

I need it inside my custom database initializer to run code like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    string.Format("DBCC CHECKIDENT ({0}, RESEED, {1})", tableName, newSeed))
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample from your database initializer and explain what you would like to change?

Comment: @marc_s: context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format("DBCC CHECKIDENT ({0}, RESEED, {1})", tableName, newSeed))

Comment: Please **don't** put code and stuff into comments - it's **REALLY** hard to read. Instead: **update** your original question by **editing it** and provide more info!

Comment: if you are not using `ToTable("tableName")` EF will assume table name as the class name. If you change your domain class name EF will change the table name too in your Initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working from the assumption that your context looks something like mine, with each of the table names getting generated from the class names when you add a DbSet to your context. If that's the case, you can achieve your goal with reflection, though it's a little ugly:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyDatabase")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Video> Video { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VideoRating> Rating { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public class Initializer : IDatabaseInitializer<DashVaultContext>
    {
        public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                context.Database.Create();

                PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(MyContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                var newSeed = 1000; // Or whatever is appropriate

                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                {
                    var tableName = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
                        string.Format("DBCC CHECKIDENT ({0}, RESEED, {1})", tableName, newSeed));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I removed the pluralization hack and just turned off pluralization in the generated table names (see the OnModelCreating override).

Comment: Right, some of our classes are mapped to table names with "s", some of them without. Anyway thanks for the idea.

Comment: @YMC I updated my answer to be more robust - I just overrode OnModelCreating to turn off pluralization of table names. That way, the name of the class is always the name of the table and my answer will always work. Of course, that's assuming you're okay with the table name always being the class name.

Comment: Ok, though it might seem slightly weird workaround to solve the task, at least it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

POCO means you can use "plain-old" CLR objects (POCO), such as existing domain objects, with your data model. These POCO data classes (also known as persistence-ignorant objects), which are mapped to entities that are defined in a data model and by definition it shouldn't be directly related to database implementation details. However, you can use constant class and Fluent mapping to facilitate your requirement in a better way

Your constant class implementation

```
public static class Constant
{
 public const string CreditCustomer = "dbo.CreditCustomer";
}
```

Your mappings goes like this

```
builder.Entity<Customer>() 
.HasKey(c => c.ID) 
.MapSingleType(c => new { 
     cid = c.ID, 
     nme = c.Name 
  } 
) 
.ToTable(Constant.Table.CreditCustomer);
```

In your dbInitializer

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
string.Format("DBCC CHECKIDENT ({0}, RESEED, {1})", Constant.Table.CreditCustomer, newSeed))
```

Comment: Right, it's workaround I've been using. The question is any direct way to find out table name through EF configuration classes to get rid of that Constant class, I do not want create constant for every table and I want my table names to be automatically updated as soon as I change correspondent domain class name.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how "active" this discussion is, it seems to me this functionality is just not provided in the current version of EF. I hope this features will be available in one of future version of EF.

Answer (score 0):

Will this code be useful at all?

```
        var query = from meta in context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
          .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
        let properties = meta is EntityType ? (meta as EntityType).Properties : null
        select new
        {
          TableName = (meta as EntityType).Name,
          Fields = from p in properties
                   select new
                   {
                     FielName = p.Name,
                     DbType = p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name
                   }
        };
```

Comment: What is MetadataWorkspace? DbContext does not have such a property

Comment: Check the following link out. It describes the possible approaches to link to ObjectContext from DbContext, where MetadataWorkspace is available:  http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/using-dynamic-data-with-ef-code-first.html